# Are Dell parts compatible with non-Dell hardware?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, dell, ethernet, sfp

I could not find the answer...

I'm about to buy this piece:
https://www.dell.com/pt-br/work/shop/intel-x710-10gb-sfp-mezzanine-adaptador-e-porta-dupla-da-dell/apd/555-bdpg/equipamentos-de-rede

Will this adapter work on custom hardware? I mean, no Dell parts on computer list.

Comment: The internal connector looks like a custom type. Therefore it may not work unless you have exactly that Dell system mentioned to connect it to.

Comment: You have noted that that's a mezzanine-type card, have you? It won't work in a PCIe slot.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware that Dell does couple its own hardware to Dell only.

But what could cause trouble is the firmware of that adapter.

Make sure you have the appropriate firmware programming software - preferably from intel. After that use the standard intel firmware and this adapter should do its job.

Answer (score 0):

A **Mezzanine Card** or PMC is a printed circuit board assembly manufactured to the IEEE P1386.1 standard. This standard combines the electrical characteristics of the PCI bus with the mechanical dimensions of the Common Mezzanine Card or CMC format (IEEE 1386 standard).

A mezzanine connector connects two parallel printed circuit boards in a stacking configuration. Many mezzanine connector styles are commercially available for this purpose, however PMC mezzanine applications usually use the 1.0 mm pitch 64 pin connector described in IEEE 1386.

Additional standards exist that define variants of the standard PMC. This is a short example:

- PMC-X (PCI-X PMC)
- PPMC
- CCPMC
- XMC (or "Switched"
- FMC (just FPGA Mezzanine)

**tldr;** mezzanine cards with a certain standard will work on mezzanine boards with the same standart. Function depends on firmware (of both).